# Cordova iOS 9.2 - photo capture

Tags: ios, html, cordova, ios9

I'm trying to take photo from Cordova built iOS app:

`<input id="imageInput" type="file" accept="image/*">`

In simulator and earlier iOS versions (7, 8) it work perfect - you can take photo from camera or choose existing from library. The problem is in app on iOS 9.2 it fails - you can see "Cancel" option only.

I tried also

`<input id="imageInput" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`
and `<input id="imageInput" type="file" accept="image/*;" capture="camera">`

but there is the same result

Comment: I think you should use cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: are you using xcode 7? which cordova version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated xcode to the latest version and it is working now